# Perl's Chomp: Chomp is removing the whole word instead of the newline

Tags: perl

I am facing issues with perl chomp function.
I have a **test.csv** as below:

```
col1,col2
vm1,fd1
vm2,fd2
vm3,fd3
vm4,fd4
```

I want to print the 2nd field of this csv. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $file = "test.csv";
open (my $FH, '<', $file);
my @array = (<$FH>);
close $FH;

foreach (@array)
{
    my @row = split (/,/,$_);
    my $var = chomp ($row[1]);     ###   <<< this is the problem
    print $var;
}
```

The output of aboe code is :

```
11111
```

I really don't know where the "1" is comming from. Actually, the last filed can be printed as below:

```
foreach (@array)
{
    my @row = split (/,/,$_);
    print $row[1];     ###  << Note that I am not printing "\n"
}
```

the output is:

```
vm_cluster
fd1
fd2
fd3
fd4
```

Now, i am using these field values as an input to the DB and the DB INSERT statement is failing due this invisible newline. So I thought chomp would help me here. instead of chomping, it gives me "11111".

Could you help me understand what am i doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Adding more information after reading loldop's responce:

If I write as below, then it will not print anything (not even the "11111" output mentioned above)

```
foreach (@array)
{
    my @row = split (/,/,$_);
    chomp ($row[1]); 
    my $var = $row[1]; 
    print $var;
}
```

Meaning, chomp is removing the last string and the trailing new line.

Comment: `chomp` return `1` if this function ending successfully. so, just `chomp $_; $mygoodvar = $_;`

Comment: @pavel: I did. But this isn't a straight forward issue answered in the documentation. Not even google.

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward to me. The documentation says *[chomp] returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments*. So it returns `1` because it has removed one newline.

Comment: @Borodin: true. But in this case, it is removing the last string as well which is undesirable. Thnaks for your time

Comment: It *isn't* removing the last string. You are chomping `$row[1]`, and it removes a newline from the end of `$row[1]`. Print the value of `$row[1]` and you will see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you see only a string of `1`s is that you are printing the value of `$val` which is the value returned from `chomp`. `chomp` doesn't return the trimmed string, it modifies its parameter in-place and returns the number of characters removed from the end. Since it always removes exactly one `"\n"` character you get a `1` output for each element of the array.

You really should `use warnings` instead of the `-w` command-line option, and there is no reason here to read the entire file into an array. But well done on using a lexical filehandle with the three-parameter form of `open`.

Here is a quick refactoring of your program that will do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'test.csv';
open my $FH, '<', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file": $!);

while (<$FH>) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split /,/;
    print $row[1], "\n";
}
```

Comment: That is it. Thanks you so much. This is working fine. I am not able to understand what was wrong in my approach though. thanks for your time.

Comment: @Dheeraj: please try to understand. You were printing the *return value from chomp*. `chomp` returns 1 so you were printing 1. Instead you should have been printing the `chomp`ed data in `$row[1]`.

Comment: Funny thing, this code works on my fedora but on ubuntu, it gives no output. they both are running perl 5.10.1

Comment: actually, on ubuntu, it doesn't show the output unless i add "\n" to the print statement. it might be bugfferring or something.

Comment: @Dheeraj: I am pretty sure that either your data file is either empty or the `open` fails. I have modified my solution above: please try this code instead as the original ignored open errors and continued regardless.

Comment: @Dheeraj: the output will certainly be buffered but should be flushed when the program exits.

Comment: I don't know. This is a weird behaviour. in fact my earlier comment about ubuntu and fedora was wrong, I was referring different columns there. It does not print anything. I tried your newered code and there were no problems in opening hte CSV file. So, My problem remains a problem. When I chomp and try to print the 3rd filed, either it does not print anything or I have to add "\n" to make it print. I cant work with this because this filed is a part of oracle INSERT statement. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

although, it is my fault at the beginning.
`chomp` function `return 1` <- result of usage this function.
also, you can find this bad example below. but it will works, if you use numbers. 
sometimes i use this cheat (don't do that! it is my bad-hack code!)
`map{/filter/ && $_;}@all_to_filter;`
instead of this, use
`grep{/filter/}@all_to_filter;`

```
foreach (@array)
{
    my @row = split (/,/,$_);
    my $var = chomp ($row[1]) * $row[1];     ###   this is bad code!
    print $var;
}

foreach (@array)
{
    my @row = split (/,/,$_);
    chomp ($row[1]);
    my $var = $row[1];  
    print $var;
}
```

Comment: the 2nd foreach loop you mentioned is not working. I have edited my original question with this information at the bottom of it.  Thnaks.

Comment: I think I should not be using "split". I am not sure but I think the 2nd field that I am looking for has some invisible characters after "split" is executed. But i can't tthink anything else apart form "split" either :)

Comment: loldop, I agree with what you have mentioned on the codepad. i have done that excersize already. but this is not working on the CSV I have mentioned. A really appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: FYI: maybe your CSV is really strange and you need to use CPAN-modules such as https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV or something nearly.

Comment: Nope, i wrote it by hand in vi editor on Ubuntu. i created this CSV my self for posting on this forum. The CSV that I am actually using is a different one but it shows exact same behavior as the one I have mentioned above. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Tested on Fedora Linux as well. Exact behavior. Thanks.

Comment: please find Borodin's answer below.

Comment: Your answer works as well. I have to add "\n" to print statement to see it on my ubuntu. but on my fedora, it shows without the "\n" as well. I was working on ubuntu and hence responded that your code does not give any "visible" output. I do not understand this odd behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to get rid of new lines you can use a regex:

```
my $var = $row[1];
$var=~s/\n//g;
```

Comment: for what reason you use substitution? it is weird for this task

Comment: Why not? Maybe it's weird but it works and matches his purpose :)

Comment: because regular expressions - expensive tool, really. this task, in fact, need only one: find last letter, compare with `\n` and delete if true. i know, that to kill a bird, you use cannon, ok. it is your style, mister Norris

Comment: this substitution also removed the last word and gives no visible output. thanks.

Comment: @loldop I don't understand the anger my friend :) Maybe I am wrong we are all trying to learn here.
@ Dheeraj Are you sure? I tested the code on my computer with the file you provided and it worked.

Comment: @raz3r it is not anger:) i become sad, when people use regexs in every task, really :) . as learning, i advise you to read the realization of regexs ;)

Comment: Well I may take a look at the documentation, I don't know what lies behind regex I have to be honest about that.

Comment: @raz3r Yes. I have seen the same behaviousr on my fedora as well as on ubuntu. as i said, something funky might be going on after I run the "split" function. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @raz3r: It seems perverse to use a regex substitution (especially a *global* one that will only ever match once) to remove the line terminator from the end of a string when there is a perfectly good built-in function `chomp` designed to do exactly that.

Comment: @raz3r: please find Borodin's answer below.

Comment: @raz3r: Your answer works as well. I have to add "\n" to print statement to see it on my ubuntu. but on my fedora, it shows without the "\n" as well. I was working on ubuntu and hence responded that your code does not give any "visible" output. I do not understand this odd behaviour

Comment: Well unfortunately I don't know about that behaviour, I tried the code both on Debian and SUSE Enterprise and had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was quite frustrated with this easy looking task bugging me for the whole day long. I really appreciate everyone who responded.

Finaly I ended up using Text::CSV perl module and then calling each of the CSV field as array reference. There was no need left to run the chomp after using Text::CSV.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;


 my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                  or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();


open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "vm.csv" or die "vm.csv: $!";

<$fh>;  ## this is to remove the column headers.

while ( my $row = $csv->getline ($fh) )
{
    print $row->[1];
}
```

and here is hte output:

```
fd1fd2fd3fd4
```

Later i was pulled these individual values and inserted into the DB.

Thanks everyone.